# How can I combine two object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

my first object like this :

```
{id: 1, quantity: 10, address: {id: 2, name: "stamford bridge", city: "london"}}
```

my second object like this :

```
{data: {id: 2, quantity: 20, address: {id: 4, name: "old traford", city: "manchester"}}, expired: "2017-08-16T06:46:02.566Z"}
```

I want to combine the object

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "group the object"? What is expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you give the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

This method can combine the properties of two objects together.

```
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
```

Or you have to change your data structure, if you're thinking about arrays.

```
var x = {id: 1, quantity: 10, address: {id: 2, name: "stamford bridge", city: "london"}}
```

and

```
var y = {data: [{id: 2, quantity: 20, address: {id: 4, name: "old traford", city: "manchester"}}], expired: "2017-08-16T06:46:02.566Z"}
```

Then you

```
y.data.push(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use the Object.assign(obj1, obj2); function to merge or else please add the sample output format you are expecting

```js
var x={id: 1, quantity: 10, address: {id: 2, name: "stamford bridge", city: "london"}}

var y={data: {id: 2, quantity: 20, address: {id: 4, name: "old traford", city: "manchester"}}, expired: "2017-08-16T06:46:02.566Z"}

var z = Object.assign(x, y);

console.log(z)
console.log(z.id)
console.log(z.data)
console.log(z.data.id)
```